# scaling images for image classification

Tags: machine-learning, classification, image-classification, image-preprocessing

I am trying to do image classificaition with a dataset that contains images of different sizes. The images are in a folder called Train, which contains 4 subfolders callsed HAZE,RAINY,SNOWY and SUNNY. I want to rescale all the images contained in these 4 subfolders. To do this, I use the following code:

```
from PIL import Image                                              
import os, sys                       

path = "/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Train"
dirs = os.listdir( path )                                       

def resize():
    for item in dirs:
        if os.path.isfile(path+item):
            im = Image.open(path+item)
            f, e = os.path.splitext(path+item)
            imResize = im.resize((254,254), Image.ANTIALIAS)
            imResize.save(f+'.png', 'png', quality=80)

resize()
```

the problem is that this piece of code doesn't do anything. I don't understand because it seems correct to me. The directory is to a google drive folder.

Can somebody please help me? Thanks in advance.

[EDIT]I have tried using the final slash:

```
path = "/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Train/"
dirs = os.listdir( path )

def resize():
for item in dirs:
    if os.path.isfile(path+item):
        im = Image.open(path+item)
        f, e = os.path.splitext(path+item)
        imResize = im.resize((200,200), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        imResize.save(f + ' resized.jpg', 'JPEG', quality=90)
```

but it tells me:

```
     OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-134-09ef2013485c> in <module>()
     13             imResize.save(f + ' resized.jpg', 'JPEG', quality=90)
     14 
---> 15 resize()

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py in open(fp, mode)
   2570         fp.close()
   2571     raise IOError("cannot identify image file %r"
-> 2572                   % (filename if filename else fp))
   2573 
   2574 #

OSError: cannot identify image file '/content/drive/My Drive/Colab 
Notebooks/Train/Untitled1.ipynb'
```

[EDIT]I have tried to create a new folder with few sample imaged, I called it prova, and it works:

```
path = '/content/drive/My Drive/prova/'
dirs = os.listdir( path )

def resize():
    for item in dirs:
        print('entered')
        if item.endswith('.jpg'):
            im = Image.open(path+item)
            f, e = os.path.splitext(path+item)
            imResize = im.resize((200,200), Image.ANTIALIAS)
            imResize.save(f + ' resized.jpg', 'JPEG', quality=90)
            print('done')

resize()
```

and it works for this sample code. So I think the problem is how to access the sub-folders.

[EDIT]Now that the images are resized, I use a generator:

```
trainingset = '/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Train'
testset = '/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Test'


batch_size = 32
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    featurewise_center=True,
    featurewise_std_normalization=True,
    #rescale = 1. / 255,
    \
    zoom_range=0.1,\
    rotation_range=10,\
    width_shift_range=0.1,\
    height_shift_range=0.1,\
    horizontal_flip=True,\
    vertical_flip=False)



train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    directory=trainingset,
    #target_size=(256, 256),
    color_mode="rgb",
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode="categorical",
    shuffle=True
)


test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    featurewise_center=True,
    featurewise_std_normalization=True,
    rescale = 1. / 255
   )



test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    directory=testset,
    #target_size=(256, 256),
    color_mode="rgb",
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode="categorical",
    shuffle=False
)

num_samples = train_generator.n
num_classes = train_generator.num_classes
input_shape = train_generator.image_shape

classnames = [k for k,v in train_generator.class_indices.items()]
```

I have commented some fields inside the Imagegenerator such as `target_size=(256, 256)` and `rescale = 1. / 255` since they rescale the image again. But after I ran this code, I try to print the images to see if they are still scaled:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 10
x,y = train_generator.next()
# x,y size is train_generator.batch_size

for i in range(0,n):
    image = x[i]
    label = y[i].argmax()  # categorical from one-hot-encoding
    print(classnames[label])
    plt.imshow(image)
    plt.show()
```

but they are all like these:

[image]

and also they are not scaled.

Why does this happens?

Comment: is it working on local dir?

Comment: Put a "/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Train/" slash after train because you are accessing the subfolders present in your directory and run this loop 4 times because when you use "+" for string concatenation it doesn't add that slash and so use it somewhat like this: r"/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Train/" this should work.

Comment: Thanks for answering. By adding the final slash something happens, but it gives me an error. I have edited the question with more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest for you to use the `walk()` [function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.walk) from the `os` package for iterating over all your (sub-)directories and files.

Below is a sample code:

```
import os

main_directory = "/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Train/"


for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(main_directory):
    for file in files:
        filepath = os.path.join(subdir, file)

        if filepath.endswith(".jpg"):
            im = Image.open(filepath)
            imResize = im.resize((200, 200), Image.ANTIALIAS)
            imResize.save(filepath[:-4] + '_resized.jpg', 'JPEG', quality=90)
```

**Pro tip**: if you want to see the progress of iterating over the different subdirectories, you can use the `tqdm` package.

```
import os

from tqdm import tqdm # pip install tqdm

main_directory = "/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Train/"


for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(main_directory):
    for file in tqdm(files, desc='Loading files from {}'.format(subdir)):
        filepath = os.path.join(subdir, file)

        if filepath.endswith(".jpg"):
            im = Image.open(filepath)
            imResize = im.resize((200, 200), Image.ANTIALIAS)
            imResize.save(filepath[:-4] + '_resized.jpg', 'JPEG', quality=90)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried your code, but the images don't get scaled

Comment: @J.D. What do you mean the images don't get scaled?
1) is the new image being created (with the `_resized) extension? 2) was was the size of the original image?

Comment: sorry, ignore my previous comment. What happens is that it gives me an error : OSError: cannot write mode RGBA as JPEG

Comment: the orginal images are all of different sizes. What I want to do is take all these images and give to all of them the same size.

Comment: did you see this? https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/2609
Seems like you cannot save as JPEG. Is saving as PNG ok for you?

Comment: I think it is ok also if it saves as PNG. But also I have the problem that if I use convert as in the link you gave me I have the error message: AttributeError: module 'PIL.Image' has no attribute 'convert'

Comment: sorry again, but I have also seen that your code add the new image to the dataset, it does not substitute it. Is there a way to substitue the image? Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

When you write `path+item`, you are not getting a valid path to a file. This is because there is no separator at the end of path. For example, if `img1.png` is in the directory, `path+item` gives “/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Trainimg1.png”.

Also, it seems you are iterating through the subdirectories but not the files within those directories.

A better way to do this is to write `os.path.join(path, dir, file)` where file is the result of iterating through dir.

Answer (score 0):

The OSError is caused by the fact that you have a `.ipynb` file in the directory which is not an image, which therefore can't be opened using `Image.open`. You should probably change your if statement so it only opens files of a specific type.

```py
path = "/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Train/"
dirs = os.listdir( path )

def resize():
    for item in dirs:
        if os.path.isfile(path+item) and item.endswith('.png'):
            im = Image.open(path+item)
            f, e = os.path.splitext(path+item)
            imResize = im.resize((200,200), Image.ANTIALIAS)
            imResize.save(f + ' resized.jpg', 'JPEG', quality=90)
```

This is assuming your image files all have a `.png` file extension. If your image files have a different extension (such as `.jpg`) you can simply change the extension.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It does not work by doing so. It doesn' t do anything.

Comment: Have you tried adding a print statement within the loop just to see whether the loop was entered or not?

Comment: yes, it enters the for loop, but it does not enter the if condition.

Comment: What types of images are you trying to read? Can you perhaps share a google colab/notebook link with your code in it?

Comment: The images are in .jpg format and represent types of weather conditions. I am able to scale them correctly by using an Image generator, but by doing so I get a warning for which I asked a question which I attach here to you https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/64402/warning-during-training-a-cnn . So to overcome this problem My idea is to scale first the images, and then use a generator and train the network. This is why I am trying to scale first, but with a generator was much easier.

Comment: If you are trying to read `.jpg` files you should change the `.endswith(".png")` to `.endwith(".jpg")` and then it should work. If it still not works try removing the `os.path.isfile(path+item)` part so your only left with `if item.endswith('.png'):`.

Comment: I did as you suggestd, but still does not work

Comment: Can you possibly share some example images so I try to see if what the problem is?

Comment: I don't know how to share a folder here on stack exchange, but I have tried to create a folder in my google drive and add to it  images just for try. By only accessing this folder your code worked fine, so the problem should be just how to access the sub folders.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Python 3.6 (or higher), `pathlib` cleans up the code by automatically walking all subdirectories and processing only images:

```py
from pathlib import Path

from PIL import Image  

path = Path('/content/drive/My Drive/prova/')

for filename in path.glob('**/*.jpg'):
    im = Image.open(filename)
    im_resized = im.resize((200,200), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    im_resized.save(filename.parent / Path(filename.stem + '_resized.jpg'), 'JPEG', quality=90)
```

Comment: Thanks, but it does not scale the images